# Costmap2DROS transform timeout

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS experts,

I am running a turtlebot with a Kobuki base and Asus Xtion Pro camera, without any dedicated laser range finder (on Ubuntu 14.04 using ROS Indigo).

When I run amcl everything runs fine and I am able to navigate using Rviz as well as my own code which uses move_base.

However, there is another node that runs, which subscribes to /camera/rgb/image_rect_color and uses the camera images to detect objects. As soon as this node starts running I start getting the below warning repeatedly:

> [ WARN] [1456505621.806228153]:
> Costmap2DROS transform timeout.
> Current time: 1456505621.8061,
> global_pose stamp: 1456505620.1919,
> tolerance: 0.5000 [ WARN]
> [1456505621.806352967]: Could not get
> robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration

After a couple of minutes, the robot is unable to navigate anywhere and all the move_base commands get aborted.

I checked the issue posted [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/215256/costmap2dros-transform-timeout/) and tried to increase the tolerance using

> rosparam set /amcl/transform_tolerance 5.0

The tolerance was set properly and I verified it using rosparam get.
. This helped for some time, but after that, the same problem reoccurred.

I checked the transform tree and saw that the frequency of map is 10000 Hz while frequency of base_link is around 5 Hz. This appears to be very strange, and it seems to me that this huge difference is somehow causing the transformation from map to base_link to fail.

Given below is a part of my tf transform tree (sorry I could not post an image since I do not have the required amount of points). The sequence is map->odom->base_footprint->base_link:

**map**
Broadcaster: /amcl
Average rate: 10000.000 Hz
Most recent transform: 1456505319.249 ( -0.752 sec old)
Buffer length: 0.000 sec

**odom**
Broadcaster: /mobile_base_nodelet_manager
Average rate: 50.556 Hz
Most recent transform: 1456505318.483 ( 0.014 sec old)
Buffer length: 4.905 sec

**base_footprint**
Broadcaster: /robot_state_publisher
Average rate: 5.208 Hz
Most recent transform: 1456505318.479 ( 0.018 sec old)
Buffer length: 4.800 sec

**base_link**
Broadcaster: /robot_state_publisher
Average rate: 5.208 Hz
Most recent transform: 1456505318.479 ( 0.018 sec old)
Buffer length: 4.800 sec

Any ideas or suggestions regarding possible solutions or pointers to what I may be doing wrong will be highly appreciated.

Best,
Sayantan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227688/costmap2dros-transform-timeout/) by [Sayantan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26087/sayantan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-02-26

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-11-03**:
Once that other node is launched, run `roswtf` in a terminal. It will give you a quick summary of things that might be problematic about your ROS network and TF tree.

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-07-27**:
hello, did you find a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ref: http://answers.ros.org/question/227638/costmap2dros-transform-timeoutcould-not-get-robot-pose-cancelling-reconfiguration/

---

Originally posted by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) with karma: 287 on 2016-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0